# mongoose array length function returning object type

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I want to find out how many tables particular user has in the schema

```js
async punishmentCount(user) {
    let arr = []
    await punishments.find({user: user}, 
    async(err,res) => {
    res.map(x => {
    arr.push(x.case)
    })
 })
    return arr.length
}
```

but I know .length is number when i logged this  **`console.log(typeof punishmentCount("3534"))`**
its return *`*object`** I want to take a number
how can I fix this?